# how to force debian to wait till the external usb HDD has synced before turning off

Tags: debian, hard-disk, synchronization, external-hdd

I think that my debian box (debian testing, rather updated) is powering off before completely syncing the external USB HDD (where I am holding my home partition at the moment). I see that when it is powering off the activity LED of the HDD is still flashing *and* it has already shown me the last 2 power ups a brief message about a check of the partitions (which is the first time I see them since I started using this box a few years ago, I think).

Is there a way in which I am able to force debian to wait for the partition/HDD to completely sync in order to power off? Or at least force it to wait a few more seconds before shutting down.

Comment: Please check if echoing `1` to `/sys/.../manage_start_stop` helps to spin down the hdd gracefully. See [bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205107#c20](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205107#c20)

Comment: Wow! Will read that later at night.... before I shutdown my computer next time. ;-)

Comment: @Freddy that would definitely be worth an answer, even if you aren't gamifying the points. (Easier for others to find your advice in the future too.)